# How could craving be the habit of reification?

Tags: craving, papanca, tanha

Below, it says that "craving" is the habit of reifying things, resulting in the notion that we need ever-increasingly more things to live happily.

How could craving (tanha) be the habit of reification (papanca)? How does it link?

From Piya Tan's commentary of [Cetana Sutta (SN 12.38-40)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/7.6abc-Cetana-S-s12.38-40-piya.pdf):

> What is interesting here is Mahā Cunda’s statement (from [MN 144](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/11.12-Channovada-S-m144-piya.pdf))
>   that rebirth and suffering are rooted in "emotional dependence"
>   (*nissita*), which the Majjhima Commentary explains as arising on
>   account of craving and view (MA 5:83). **"Craving" is the habit of
>   reifying people, things and ideas, resulting in the notion that we
>   need "more and more" to live happily;** "view" is the delusion that
>   sustains and moves craving, and its necessary opposite, hate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reification is simpistic naive superficial perception. It's a generalization of the same problem that children have with toys. A child sees a new shiny toy and because he does not think deeply, because his perception is superficial - in his mind the toy is attractive and desirable.

Reification is seeing the outer image and buying into its glow, its fake promise to make you happy.

Comment: Does this 'perception' you are referring to apply to every sense object? Also relationships etc.?

Comment: Yes, of course.